# Force other developers to call method after completing their work

Tags: java

In a library in Java 7, I have a class which provides services to other classes. After creating an instance of this service class, one method of it may be called several times (let’s call it the `doWork()` method). So I do not know when the work of the service class is completed.

The problem is the service class uses heavy objects and it should release them. I set this part in a method (let’s call it `release()`), but it is not guaranteed that other developers will use this method.

Is there a way to force other developers to call this method after completing the task of service class? Of course I can document that, but I want to force them.

Note: I cannot call the `release()` method in the `doWork()` method, because `doWork()`  needs those objects when it is called in next.

Comment: What you are doing there is a form of temporal coupling and typically considered a code smell. You may want to force yourself to come up with a better design instead.

Comment: @Frank I'd agree, if changing the design of the underlying layer is an option then that would be the best bet. But I suspect this is a wrapper around someone else's service.

Comment: Which kind of heavy objects your Service needs? If the Service class is not able to manage those resources automatically by itself (without requiring temporal coupling) then perhaps those resources should be managed elsewhere and injected to the Service. Have you written unit tests for the Service class?

Comment: It is very "un-Java" to require that. Java is a language with garbage collection and now you come up with some kind of contraption in which you require developers to "clean up".

Comment: Can you use automated testing and continuous-integration to test these classes with unit or integration tests?

Comment: @PieterB why? `AutoCloseable` was made for this exact purpose.

Comment: @BgrWorker AutoCloseable is fine. It solves the problem of the question asker. But the way the question is asked, it asks for cleaning up after.....the difference may be subtle.

Comment: A key question when talking about forcing others to do things: what do you want to do if they fail to satisfy their end of the bargin?  Bail out with an exception?  A warning message? Undefined behavior?  Or do you want to have a programmatic concept of taking the resources back from the worker.  Can the worker hold your entire program hostage by not playing ball?

Comment: @BgrWorker - `AutoCloseable` was made to solve basically the same issue that the OP has created, yes.  But that tends to prove Pieter's point.  "un-Java" may not have been the best description, however having objects that need to be explicitly closed _is a problem_.  It's such a big problem that _a major feature was added to the language_ to mitigate it.  As Pieter suggests, it would be better to restructure the code to follow a pattern that doesn't require a call to `release()`, `close()`, or the use of a `try-with-resources` block.

Comment: Note: I cannot call the release() method in the doWork() method, because doWork() needs those objects when it is called in next. -> Do you use the objects as some kind of cache?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The pragmatic solution is to make the class `AutoCloseable`, and provide a `finalize()` method as a backstop (if appropriate ... see below!).  Then you rely on users of your class to use *try-with-resource* or call `close()` explicitly.

> Of course I can document that, but I want to force them.

Unfortunately, there is no way<sup>1</sup> in Java to force the programmer to do the right thing.  The best you could hope to do is to pick up incorrect usage in a static code analyser.

---

On the topic of finalizers.  This Java feature has very few **good** use cases.  If you rely on finalizers to tidy up, you run into the problem that it can take a very long time for the tidy-up to happen.  The finalizer will only be run *after* the GC decides that the object is no longer reachable.  That may not happen until the JVM does a *full* collection.

Thus, if the problem you are tying to solve is to reclaim resources that need to be released *early*, then you have missed the boat by using finalization.

And just in case you haven't got what I am saying above ... it is **almost never** appropriate to use finalizers in production code, and you should **never** rely on them!

---

<sup>1 - There are ways.  If you are prepared to "hide" the service objects from user code or tightly control their lifecycle (e.g. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/345100/172) then the users code doesn't *need* to call `release()`.  However, the API becomes more complicated, restricted ... and "ugly" IMO.  Also, this is not *forcing the programmer to do the right thing*.  It is removing the programmer's ability to do the wrong thing!</sup>

Comment: Finalizers teach a very bad lesson - if you screw it, I'll fix it for you. I prefer netty's approach -> a configuration parameter that instructs the (ByteBuffer) factory to randomly create with probability of X% bytebuffers with a finalizer that prints the location where this buffer was acquired (if not already released). So in production this value can be set to 0% - i.e no overhead, and during testing & dev to a higher value like 50% or even 100% in order to detect the leaks before releasing the product

Comment: and remember that finalizers are not guaranteed to ever run, even if the object instance is being garbage collected!

Comment: I agree with both comments above.  100%.

Comment: "Unfortunately, there is no way in Java to force the programmer to do the right thing." See my answer below for a way to force this behaviour in this particular case.

Comment: It's worth noting that Eclipse emits a compiler warning if an AutoCloseable is not closed. I'd expect other Java IDE to do so, as well.

Comment: @jwenting In what case don't they run when the object is GC'd? I couldn't find any resource stating or explaining that.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach several cases. For example if the JVM terminates (say an exception) finalize is never called. Also, if the object is revived in finalize, it's never called again even if the object gets garbage collected in the future. Also, if an object is garbage collected, finalizers on its parent classes are not executed, unless explicitly called. If you don't believe me, maybe Brian Goetz can convince you: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp01274/

Comment: @Svetlin "No overhead"? Having a finalizer has quite the overhead even if it later turns out it does nothing. That's the problem with Java not having something like C#'s `GC.SuppressFinalize` to avoid the performance hit to the GC if the finalizer would be unnecssary (generally called in Dispose). Not sure if using a constant bool which is removed during compilation would allow the JVM to optimize the finalize method away - if it does, that might be an option.

Comment: @Voo You misunderstood my comment. You have two implementations -> `DefaultResource` and `FinalizableResource` which extends the first one and adds a finalizer. In production you use `DefaultResource` which does not have finalizer->no overhead. During development and testing you configure the app to use `FinalizableResource` which has a finalizer and hence adds overhead. During dev and testing that's not an issue, but it can help you identify leaks and fix them before reaching production. Yet if a leaks reaches PRD you can configure the factory to create X% `FinalizableResource` to id the leak

Comment: @Svetlin I thought you meant a simple if check in the finalize. With your way you avoid this problem nicely.

Comment: What about checking if the object was closed in the finalize() and if not, throw an exception with a request to close the object after it has been used. This way even if the finalize is not guaranteed to be called you can be reasonably sure that the developer will encounter the exception while developing the app, and be forced to add the close method

Comment: `AutoClosable` is great, but you still have to rely on people using the `with()...` idiom. With lambda functions, you can *force* your callers to use resource control - see Venkat Subramaniam: *Functional Programming in Java*.

Comment: _This Java feature has very few good use cases_  It has very few good use cases because it's broken by design, i.e. finalisers are not called so one cannot use them. It _would_ have many good uses, that don't have to do with "releasing system resources" but actually with program logic, such as verifying certain things took place, or doing things in pairs. The school of though that "while I still have memory, why should I run finalisers, dispose, garbage collect" completely misses the point.

Answer (score 55):

This seems like the use-case for [`AutoCloseable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) and the [`try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) introduced in Java 7. If you have something like

```
public class MyService implements AutoCloseable {
    public void doWork() {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // release resources
    }
}
```

then your consumers can use it as

```
public class MyConsumer {
    public void foo() {
        try (MyService myService = new MyService()) {
            //...
            myService.doWork()
            //...
            myService.doWork()
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

and not have to worry about calling an explicit `release` regardless of whether their code throws an exception.

---

*Additional answer*

If what you are really looking for is to ensure that no one can forget to use your function, you have to do a couple of things

1. Ensure all constructors of `MyService` are private.
2. Define a single point of entry to use `MyService` that ensures it is cleaned up after.

You would do something like

```
public interface MyServiceConsumer {
    void accept(MyService value);
}

public class MyService implements AutoCloseable {
    private MyService() {
    }


    public static void useMyService(MyServiceConsumer consumer) {
        try (MyService myService = new MyService()) {
            consumer.accept(myService)
        }
    }
}
```

You would then use it as

```
public class MyConsumer {
    public void foo() {
        MyService.useMyService(new MyServiceConsumer() {
            public void accept(MyService myService) {
                myService.doWork()
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I did not recommend this path originally because it is hideous without Java-8 lambdas and functional interfaces (where `MyServiceConsumer` becomes `Consumer<MyService>`) and it is fairly imposing on your consumers. But if what you only want is that `release()` must get called, it will work.

Comment: This answer is probably better than mine. My way has a delay before the Garbage Collector kicks in.

Comment: How do you ensure that clients will use `try-with-resources` and not just omit the `try`, thus missing the `close` call?

Comment: @walpen This way has the same problem. How I can force the user to use `try-with-resources`?

Comment: @Frank / @hasanghaforian, Yes, this way does not force close to be called. It does have the benefit of familiarity: Java developers know you really should make sure `.close()` is called when the class implements `AutoCloseable`.

Comment: @hasanghaforian, I have added on an option that should meet your requirements. I do think you should trust your consumers enough to remember to close your classes when you follow conventions.

Comment: Couldn't you pair a finalizer with a `using` block for deterministic finalization?   At least in C#, this becomes a pretty clear pattern for developers to get in the habit of using when leveraging resources that need deterministic finalization.  Something easy and habit forming is the next best thing when you can't force someone to do something. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2016311/84206

Comment: @AaronLS, as StephenC's answer and its comments note: finalizers can be arbitrarily delayed or even never run. If all you want is a best-effort that your resources are released, then a finalizer is serviceable. Even then ideally you log on finalize being called without close as you should treat that as an error.

Comment: @walpen I think the distinction is that when you depend on the the GC to call the finalizer, then it is nondeterministic, thus delayed and not guaranteed. The example given no longer relies on the GC to call the finalizer. It is equivalent to an explicit final block, which my understanding guarantees the finalizer is called: https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_updated_arm_spec

Comment: @AaronLS, `try-with-resources` calls `AutoCloseable.close()` and not `Object.finalize()` so I'm not really sure what you are saying.

Comment: In case you need to point to precedent, C# has IDisposable with the same functionality. It has many examples online and a good one I use is managing streams or network connections.

Comment: @walpen Since his goal is to guarantee a .release() call, he can implement that in .close().  Of course it requires developers to follow the try-with-resources pattern, but patterns are easier to form habits around than making them memorize specific method calls for certain classes.

Comment: @hasanghaforian Cleaning up after yourself is an old problem, and you should learn from standard language APIs. The classic example is closing a file. We've settled on try-with-resources style language constructs in several (most?) modern languages. It doesn't *force* anyone to do anything, but it makes doing the right thing *very* easy. Developers who don't leverage them whenever possible
 are either inexperienced or incompetent enough you don't want them writing production code in the first place.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm agree and so I accepted this answer: `http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/345068/174635`

Answer (score 55):

## Yes you can

You can absolutely force them to release, and make it so it is 100% impossible to forget, by making it impossible for them to create new `Service` instances.

If they did something like this before:

```
Service s = s.new();
try {
  s.doWork("something");
  if (...) s.doWork("something else");
  ...
}
finally {
  s.release(); // oops: easy to forget
}
```

Then change it so they must access it like this.

```
// Their code

Service.runWithRelease(new ServiceConsumer() {
  void run(Service s) {
    s.doWork("something");
    if (...) s.doWork("something else");
    ...
  }  // yay! no s.release() required.
}

// Your code

interface ServiceConsumer {
  void run(Service s);
}

class Service {

   private Service() { ... }      // now: private
   private void release() { ... } // now: private
   public void doWork() { ... }   // unchanged

   public static void runWithRelease(ServiceConsumer consumer) {
      Service s = new Service();
      try {
        consumer.run(s);
      }
      finally {
        s.release();
      } 
    } 
  }
```

Caveats:

- Consider this pseudocode, it has been ages since I've written Java.
- There might be more elegant variants around these days, maybe including that `AutoCloseable` interface someone mentioned; but the given example should work out of the box, and except for elegantness (which is a nice goal in itself) there should be no major reason to change it. *Note that this intends to say that you could use `AutoCloseable` inside your private implementation; the benefit of my solution over having your users use `AutoCloseable` is that it can, again, not be forgotten.*
- You'll have to flesh it out as needed, for example to inject arguments into the `new Service` call.
- As mentioned in the comments, the question of whether a construct like this (i.e., taking the process of creating and destroying a `Service`) belongs in the hand of the caller or not is outside of the scope of this answer. But if you decide that you absolutely need this, this is how you can do it.
- One commenter provided this information regarding exception handling: [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=2QfzBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=hole%20in%20the%20middle%20pattern%20%20Brian%20Hurt&source=bl&ots=mbnpIy1EgR&sig=tdqlIR_poHYPVIz2-vJ7laT5_qU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj36fzyuvvSAhUlxoMKHWmHAkQQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=hole%20in%20the%20middle%20pattern%20%20Brian%20Hurt&f=false)

Comment: I am happy about comments for the downvote, so I can improve the answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this design is likely to be more trouble than it's worth. It adds a great deal of complexity and imposes a large burden on callers. Developers should be familiar enough with try-with-resources style classes that using them is second nature whenever a class implements the appropriate interface, so that is typically good enough.

Comment: @jpmc26, funnily I feel that that approach *reduces* complexity and burden on the *callers* by saving them from thinking about the resource lifecycle at all. Aside from that; the OP did not ask "should I force the users..." but "how do I force the users". And if it is important enough, this is one solution that works very well, is structurally simple (just wrapping it in a closure/runnable), even transferable to other languages which have lambdas/procs/closures as well. Well, I'll leave it to the SE democracy to judge; the OP has already decided anyways. ;)

Comment: Except the caller probably *needs* to think about the lifecycle, and control over it would probably be useful. Every so often, you run into a situation where you need a little more control than the original author foresaw. This design means the entire class becomes useless to you in that situation, or forces you into some insane work around. The lifecycle of objects that consume resources is typically something you should always make a decision about. It certainly doesn't reduce complexity. It introduces an addition method to the class and forces all callers to implement an extra function.

Comment: Again, @jpmc26, I'm not that much interested in discussing whether this approach is correct for any single use case out there. The OP *asks how to enforce such a thing* and this answer *tells how to enforce such a thing*. It is not for us to decide whether it is appropriate to do so in the first place. The technique shown is a tool, nothing more, nothing less, and useful to have in ones bag-of-tools, I believe.

Comment: Which is why I didn't downvote. But in the majority of situations, that level of restrictiveness is an undue burden and more likely to be problematic. The cases where this is the best idea would be rare. I'm having trouble thinking of any outside of your coworkers being utterly incompetent, but this would be a poor solution to someone else's incompetence. So I can understand why someone would downvote on that basis. Maybe if your caveats section mentioned these design drawbacks, the downvoter would have refrained.

Comment: This is the correct answer imho, it is essentially the hole-in-the-middle pattern

Comment: I prefer this answer to the others but it's not showing where `void doWork() { ... }` should be defined.

Comment: Yeah, this is good.

Comment: If you want to do this but need to deal with exceptions [give this a read](https://books.google.com/books?id=2QfzBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=hole+in+the+middle+pattern++Brian+Hurt&source=bl&ots=mbnpIy1EgR&sig=tdqlIR_poHYPVIz2-vJ7laT5_qU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj36fzyuvvSAhUlxoMKHWmHAkQQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=hole%20in%20the%20middle%20pattern%20%20Brian%20Hurt&f=false)

Comment: Thank you, @CandiedOrange, I've included it in the answer.

Comment: @AnoE most welcome. Still don't see where you want `doWork() {...}` defined.

Comment: `doWork` stays as is (i.e., `Service.doWork()`), the `Service` class itself does not need to change in any way (except for making the constrcutor/`release()` private/protected). I've updated the answer.

Comment: Note also that ServiceConsumer is a functional interface so other developers could put their code in a lambda: Service.runWithRelease((service) -> service.doWork());

Comment: For the record, pointing out that something is probably a bad idea isn't out of the scope of any question. Ever. And especially explaining why it is.

Comment: @jmpc26, you seem to be on a crusade here. Pointing out why it is bad is out of the scope of *my* answer because I generally see nothing bad in using functional constructs like this in cases where it fits whatever needs the developer has. I do absolutely not think or agree that this is "probably a bad idea". Feel free to add your own answer where you lay out your reasoning why it's bad to do things like this, I find it rather pointless going on and on in the comments about this.

Comment: @AneE I just wanted to see you showing where `doWork() {...}` should be defined. Your 6th edit shows that perfectly well.  Nice answer.

Comment: The OP wanted to be able to call doWork() multiple times before release has to be called. I fail to see if this solution accounts for that?

Comment: Yes, @ZeroOne, within the closure (the `runWithRelease` provided by the "user") they can do anything, as much as they want. I'll update the answer to make that more visible.

Comment: This is actually a good answer and, if anything else, it gives a really good hint on engineering your software.

Comment: I was thinking about making an analyzer, but this is now much simpler... smart solution!

Comment: An additional Java 8 version of the resulting code showing how to do it with Lambdas would be instructive.

Comment: Is your calling of Service.runWithRelease missing a closing ")"?   I think it needs it before the "// yay!" comment.

Answer (score 11):

You could try to make use of the *Command* pattern.

```
class MyServiceManager {

    public void execute(MyServiceTask tasks...) {
        // set up everyting
        MyService service = this.acquireService();
        // execute the submitted tasks
        foreach (Task task : tasks)
            task.executeWith(service);
        // cleanup yourself
        service.releaseResources();
    }

}
```

This gives you full control over resource acquisition and release. The caller only submits tasks to your Service, and you yourself are responsible for acquiring and cleaning up resources.

There is a catch, however. The caller can still do this:

```
MyServiceTask t1 = // some task
manager.execute(t1);
MyServiceTask t2 = // some task
manager.execute(t2);
```

But you can adress this problem when it arisis. When there are performance problems and you find out that some caller do this, simply show them the proper way and resolve the issue:

```
MyServiceTask t1 = // some task
MyServiceTask t2 = // some task
manager.execute(t1, t2);
```

You can make this arbitrarly complex by implementing promises for tasks that are dependent on other tasks, but then releasing stuff also gets more complicated. This is only a starting point.

## Async

As has been pointed out in the comments, the above doesn't really work with asynchronous requests. Thats correct. But this can easily be solved in Java 8 with the use of [CompleteableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), especially `CompleteableFuture#supplyAsync` to create the individual futures and `CompleteableFuture#allOf` to perfom the release of the resources once *all* tasks have finished.
Alternatively, one can always use Threads or ExecutorServices to roll their own implementation of Futures/Promises.

Comment: I would appreciate it if downvoters leave a comment why they think this is bad, so that I can either adress those concerns directly or at least get another point of view for the future. Thanks!

Comment: +1 upvote. This may be an approach, but service is async and the consumer needs to get the first result before asking for the next service.

Comment: This is just a barebones template. JS solves this with promises, you could do similar things in Java with futures and a collector that is called when all tasks are finished and then cleans up. Its definitely possible to get async and even dependencies in there, but it also complicates things a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, do not allow the user to create the resource. Let the user pass a visitor object to your method, which will create the resource, pass it to the visitor object's method, and release afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but excuse me, do you mean that it is better to pass resources to the consumer and then get it again when he ask for service? Then the problem will remain: Consumer may forget to release those resources.

Comment: If you want to control a resource, don't let go of it, don't pass it to someone else's flow of execution completely. One way to do it is to run a predefined method of a user's visitor object. `AutoCloseable` does a very similar thing behind the scenes. Under another angle, it's similar to [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 1):

My idea was similar to Polygnome's.

You can have the "do_something()" methods in your class just add commands to a private command list. Then, have a "commit()" method that actually does the work, and calls "release()".

So, if the user never calls commit(), the work is never done. If they do, the resources are freed.

```
public class Foo
{
  private ArrayList<ICommand> _commands;

  public Foo doSomething(int arg) { _commands.Add(new DoSomethingCommand(arg)); return this; }
  public Foo doSomethingElse() { _commands.Add(new DoSomethingElseCommand()); return this; }

  public void commit() { 
     for(ICommand c : _commands) c.doWork();
     release();
     _commands.clear();
  }

}
```

You can then use it like foo.doSomething.doSomethineElse().commit();

Comment: This is the same solution, but instead of asking the caller to maintain the task list you maintain it internally. The core concept is literally the same. But this does not follow any coding conventions for Java I have ever seen and is actually quite hard to read (loop body on the same line as loop header, _ in the beginning).

Comment: Yes, it is the command pattern. I just put down some code to give a gist of what I was thinking in as concise a way as possible. I mostly write C# these days, where private variables are often prefixed with _.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of extending `AutoCloseable` is good, but it makes no guarantee.  It relies on developers to always use the try-with-resources statement.  It also assumes that using try-with-resources is possible, which it is not when one method creates a resource and another method disposes of it.

An alternative is to use the [Resource Leak Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#resource-leak-checker) of the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/).  A programmer runs the checker at compile time.  If it issues no warnings, then the code is guaranteed to call the given method.  The Resource Leak Checker can be used with or without the `AutoCloseable`-and-try-with-resources pattern.  The Resource Leak Checker works out of the box with the `Closeable` type, but you can guarantee the calling of any method, not just `close()`.  The Resource Leak Checker is used on Apache Cassandra and at Microsoft, Oracle, Uber, etc.

Of course, if a client programmer doesn't run the Resource Leak Checker (as a javac plugin) at compile time, then you still have no guarantee.

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative to the ones mentioned would be the usage of "smart references" to manage your encapsulated resources in a way which enables the garbage collector to automatically clean up without manually freeing resources. Their usefulness depends of course on your implementation.
Read more on this topic in this wonderful blog post: https://community.oracle.com/blogs/enicholas/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I cannot see how using weak references solves the OP's problem. The service class does not know whether it is going to get another doWork() request. If it releases its reference to its heavy objects, and then it gets another doWork() call, it will fail.

Answer (score -4):

For any other Class Oriented language I'd say put it in the destructor, but since that's not an option I think you can override the finalize method. That way when the instance goes out of scope and is garbage collected it will be released.

```
@Override
public void finalize() {
    this.release();
}
```

I'm not too familiar with Java, but I think that this is the purpose for which finalize() is intended.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()

Comment: This is a bad solution to the problem for the reason Stephen says in his answer - `If you rely on finalizers to tidy up, you run into the problem that it can take a very long time for the tidy-up to happen. The finalizer will only be run after the GC decides that the object is no longer reachable. That may not happen until the JVM does a full collection.`

Comment: And even then the finalizer may not in fact run...

Comment: Finalizers are notoriously unreliable: they may run, they may never run, if they run there is no guarantee _when_ they will run. Even the Java architects such as [Josh Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) say finalizers are a terrible idea (reference: [Effective Java (2nd Edition)](https://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683)).

Comment: These kind of issues make me miss C++ with its deterministic destruction and RAII...